# How to configure transactor in doobie?

Tags: mysql, scala, intellij-idea, hikaricp, doobie

Recently I started learning doobie but I couldn't create a hikari transactor without error. I'm using mysql, Intellij-Idea.

This is my build.sbt file

```
name := "doobie"
version := "0.1"
//scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification" // 2.11.9+
libraryDependencies ++= {
  lazy val doobieVersion = "0.8.4"
  Seq(
    "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-core"      % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-h2"            % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-hikari"        % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-quill"         % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-specs2"        % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-scalatest"     % doobieVersion   % "test",
    "mysql"           % "mysql-connector-java"  % "8.0.17",
    "org.slf4j"       % "slf4j-api"             % "1.7.5",
    "ch.qos.logback"  % "logback-classic"       % "1.0.9"
  )
}

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)
```

This is my Connection.scala file

```
import cats.effect.IO
import com.zaxxer.hikari.{HikariConfig, HikariDataSource}
import doobie.hikari.HikariTransactor

trait Connection {

  val config = new HikariConfig()
  config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:quill_demo")
  config.setUsername("admin")
  config.setPassword("password")
  config.setMaximumPoolSize(5)

  val transactor: IO[HikariTransactor[IO]] =
    IO.pure(HikariTransactor.apply[IO](new HikariDataSource(config)))

}
```

The problem is in above file `IO.pure(HikariTransactor.apply[IO](new HikariDataSource(config)))` statement gives error. Here 3 of last closed braces gives 3 errors as below.

```
No implicit arguments of type: ContextShift[IO]
```

```
Unspecified value parameters: connectEC: ExecutionContext, transactEC: ExecutionContext
```

```
No implicits found for parameter evidence$2: ContextShift[IO]
```

All I want to know, How to do this correctly.

Comment: Why don't use a Resource to manage transactor? look here https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/14-Managing-Connections.html#using-a-hikaricp-connection-pool

Comment: I tried it and didn't work.

Comment: It's strange, what is the error?

Comment: @gekomad, some keywords give "Cannot resolve symbol" error. Anyway, I solve the problem by downgrading versions. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I change the versions of dependencies as follows, I could solve all errors.

```
name := "doobie"
version := "0.1"
//scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
libraryDependencies ++= {
  lazy val doobieVersion = "0.5.4"
  Seq(
    "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-core"      % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-h2"            % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-hikari"        % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-quill"         % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-specs2"        % doobieVersion,
    "org.tpolecat"    %% "doobie-scalatest"     % doobieVersion   % "test",
    "mysql"           % "mysql-connector-java"  % "5.1.34",
    "org.slf4j"       % "slf4j-api"             % "1.7.5",
    "ch.qos.logback"  % "logback-classic"       % "1.0.9"
  )
}

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following import and implicit

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

implicit val cs = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
```

Comment: When I add above 2 lines, code will give new error `Unspecified value parameters: connectEC: ExecutionContext, blocker:Blocker` rather than previous 3 errors